# Endgame statistics

Tags: endgame

I am looking for information on W/D/L results for specific endgame configurations based on perfect play, not based on databases of actual games.

For example, in the endgame King plus Rook vs King plus Pawn (KRKP) this website (http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/nulp/results.html) says there over 9 million unique legal positions (9,041,298 to be exact).  However, there is no information on how many of those positions are w/d/l with white to move or black to move, and based on perfect play.

The closest I have found is this website (http://chess.jaet.org/endings/docs/) however these results are based on analyzing a database of actual games, which therefore means imperfect play.

Does anyone know if this has already been done and wehre I might find the results?  If not, does anyone know how to go about generating these results on your own?  I assume an EGTB can do this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Dan, the files you link to from chess.jaet.org *are* based on perfect play, not databases of actual games. For instance, the "Summary of Ken Thompson's 6-man results" is an analysis based on Thompson's 6-man tablebases.

Comment: So in particular, I think the KRKP entry in the "3-5 Man Results and Maximals" file provides the w/d/l percentages you are after. This source came up in my answer to [an earlier question](http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/8724/167) actually. If that question/answer subsume what you're after here, this post might best be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: This is link only, so probably not suited as an answer (?), but here is a spreadsheet, with exactly what you need (although, as ETD points out, you already do have some of it in your own links...). http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/discussion-board/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6941#p76732

Comment: Ah, I see I thought I had read that it was based on actual games...

Comment: Is it possible to somehow generate a string of FEN's for all possible KRKP positions?  For example if I wanted to see all positions that are draws with white to move?

Comment: Dan, I suggest asking that as a new question. For now, I am going to close this post as a duplicate of the one I linked to in my previous comment, as I think they cover the same ground. @GloriaVictis, that is a good find, and is exactly the sort of source missing from my answer to the aforementioned post. If you could add a little bit of explanation of the contents beyond just the link, I think that would be a great answer to that older question (it'll get my vote at least).